# How to get the explanations from Grakn in Python

Tags: vaticle-typedb, vaticle-typeql

I'm trying to get the explanation of an inferred relation using the Grakn Python driver.

I am using this command to get the explanations as per the documentation:

`answer.explanation().get_answers()`

But the result I get is this:

`[<grakn.service.Session.util.ResponseReader.ConceptMap object at 0x10ef70d68>, <grakn.service.Session.util.ResponseReader.ConceptMap object at 0x10ef70dd8>, <grakn.service.Session.util.ResponseReader.ConceptMap object at 0x10ef898d0>]`

How do I get the actual data that is in this list?

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing in the `list` is a set of answers, just like you would get back from Grakn from a simple `match...get;` query! So, for instance, if you wanted to print out the contents of sub-answer:

```
for explanation_answer in answer.explanation().get_answers():
  print(explanation_answer.map())
```

Keep in mind that as of Grakn 1.8.0, you need to provide a new `explain=True` flag in: `Transaction.query("...", explain=True)` [python clients] if you want to retrieve explanations later in the transaction :) The default is `explain=False`.